# How to instantiate a set of different object from json list without switch case?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I want to instantiate a set of object from a json list.

Consider the json list

```
[
   {
...
      "class":"object1",
      "area":45
...
   },
   {
...
      "class":"object2",
      "colour":"red"
   },
   {
...
      "class":"object3",
      "height":90
...
   }
]
```

Surely there are other fields that define each object. For each object I created a record

```
public record object1 (String area, ...) {}

public record object2 (String colour, ...) {}

public record object3 (String height, ...) {}
```

In general I could create a switch case that checks the property class and the chooses the correct record constructor. This seems to me very bad style. In the past I used polymorphism  with a fitting super class. and used an enum that created the object.  In this case the `record` class only has object as super.

I want to stick with record since its I am only holding simple data inside this object.

There I was wondering how to handle this. What is the best practice to handle something like this? What pattern can be used to solve this?

Comment: You could try to use a library that already supports this, e.g. Jackson (albeit "class" might have to be the FQCN). If you want to do it yourself, try a meta factory/factory repository, e.g. 1) you call the meta factory with the value of "class" to get the actual object factory and 2) you pass the record data to that factory to have it create the actual instance.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I might have to it myself since there might me a database in the back in the future so I might need to adjust it myself. Do you have a example of this meta factory/factory repository pattern I could go over?

Comment: I'll add one in an answer to give you a start

Answer (score 3):

I'll expand a little on my comment to show a rough example of what the "meta factory" approach could look like.

First, you define an interface for the actual object factories. I'll leave the implementations for you, those are pretty straight forward (just like what your cases in the switch block would have been doing).

```
interface Factory<T> { 
  //I'll assume you're using a JSON library here which provided a JsonObject class
  //Change the parameter as required to reflect your actual code
  T createInstance(JsonObject record);
}
```

Then create a repository. This also is just a rough outline:

```
class FactoryRepo {
  //Mapping between name and type, this could also be maintained by the factories or some other piece of code
  Map<String, Class<?>> typeMapping = ...;

  //The actual repository, a simple map for starters
  Map<Class<?>, Factory<?>> repository = ...;

  //register a new factory, I'll add the name mapping too but you could move this into a separate method
  public <T> void registerFactory(String name, Class<T> type, Factory<T> factory) {
    typeMapping.put(name, type);
    repository.put(type, factory);
  }

  //lookup factory by class
  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
  public <T> Factory<T> lookupFactory(Class<T> type) {
    //unfortunately this cast is necessary
    return (Factory<T>)repository.get(type);
  }
      
  //lookup factory by name
  public Factory<?> lookupFactory(String name) {
    return lookupFactory(typeMapping.get(name));
  }
}
```

Of course, you need to register the factories. This can be done manually or by using frameworks that detect implementations (e.g. Spring, CDI or even Java's SPI). A manual approach could look like this:

```
 FactoryRepo repo = ...; //get if from somewhere

 repo.registerFactory("object1", Object1Type.class, new Object1Factory());
 repo.registerFactory("object2",ColoredObject.class, record -> {
   //code to build an instance of ColoredObject from record and return it
 });
```

Finally, you use it:

```
 FactoryRepo repo = ...; //get if from somewhere

 JsonObject record = ...; //assumes you have it handy

 //Unfortunately, you only get "Object" since the record's class can be anything
 //If you have an interfacy etc. you could limit the boundary to this
 Factory<?> factory = repo.lookupFactory(record.get("class"));
 Object instance = factory.createInstance(record);


 //If you know the type, you can try like this:
 ColoredObject co = repo.lookupFactory(ColoredObject.class).createInstance(record);
```

Comment: Cool this is good jumping off point. There are some smaller details I am missing. or like to clarify. I assume the  `Object1Factory` implements the interface `Factory` correct? There is a lot of moving parts do you have an link for this specific implementation. I looked for the factory pattern but the examples are rather basic with abstract classes. In any case I  thanks for the great hints.

Comment: One followup question would be how to instantiate the `Map<String, Class<?>> typeMapping`  and the `repository`? Am I supposed to use a `new HashMap<>()` and put in entries?

Comment: @A.Dumas no, I've used this pattern quite a lot but don't have any link to share. It's probably best to play around with it a little and split the approach into distinct parts: 1) implementations of the `Factory` interface (and yes, `Object1Factory` is one of them), 2) How to initialize the repository - start with manual registration and then work your way to runtime detection and 3) The repository itself, as might need some additional checks and synchronization, depending on your needs. For starters, the maps in the repository can be simple `HashMap` or `ConcurrentMap` instances.

Comment: You are just amazing. I just tested it and it work like a charm. I still need to make some clean code arrangements and some adjustments about the encapsulation but it was just a blast. I assume there must be one controlling logic that takes the correct `repo.lookupFactory` if I wanted a the correct object. but this is awesome. 

I have to say this should be a  blog entry somewhere since it is just great

Comment: @A.Dumas you're welcome :) - the controlling logic would basically iterate over the json array, check each of the objects, pull the "class" field and finally look up the factory.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer! I have a question: I feel like this factory strategy is a bit overkill for a relatively harmless problem (having a switch statement to instantiate the classes). I'm trying to find ways to limit branching in my code, but am wondering what are the practical benefits of this approach over the switch statement?

Comment: @joshpetit it's a good approach to think about the pros and cons of a pattern instead of blindly applying it. Unfortunately I can't cover everything here and you might need to do some research or tests on your own to gain experience with the pattern but let me try to provide a few guiding questions: What is easier to understand and maintain? What code would need to be changed if there are changes to existing classes or new ones added? If code is distributed could there be a risk of related parts deviating because some are forgotten?

Comment: @Thomas, interesting guiding questions, thanks for the response 